# Can not execute maven command: mvn appengine:update

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

After updating to Appengine version 1.9.10 I can not directly deploy my application on AppEngine using maven command mvn appengine:update and the below exception is raised:

> [ERROR] Could not find goal 'update;' in plugin
>   com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.10 among available
>   goals create-property, devserver, backends_configure,
>   gcloud_app_run_stop, gcloud_app_deploy, vacuum_indexes,
>   backends_rollback, set_default_version, debug, update_queues,
>   devserver_stop, backends_update, update, backends_stop, rollback,
>   endpoints_get_discovery_doc, backends_start, devserver_start,
>   start_module_version, endpoints_get_client_lib, gcloud_app_run_start,
>   update_dispatch, enhance, backends_delete, update_dos, gcloud_app_run,
>   update_cron, stop_module_version, update_indexes -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
>   debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors
>   and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
>   [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to link everything with 1.9.10.  After looking at a bit of Google documentation, I figured my problem was not related to 1.9.10.

Seemed like my problem had to do with multiple logins, so here is what I did :

1- I went to "C:\Users[MY USERNAME]" and I deleted the ".appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java"

2- I logged out of EVERY gmail/google product I had (on ALL my chrome sessions).

3- I retried, making sure to use the correct email when it asked for the oauth2.0 token

4- Voila!

let me know if this fixes your issue.  My project now function whether I have 1.9.9 or 1.9.10 in my pom.xmls :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after restarting my machine the issue has been fixed.